# float sub-class to alter intake and __str__ behaviour

Tags: python, python-3.x, subclass

I've sub-classed float to alter its `__str__()` method to end with a symbol (in my case €).

The input is filtered to remove a symbol (in my case €).

```
class Euro(float):
    def __new__(cls, value):
        v = ''.join([_ for  _ in value if _ != '€' ])
        return super(Euro, cls).__new__(cls, v)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self} €'
```

But when I print, I get a recursive print error.

```
g = Euro('123.23 €')
print (g)
```

Error:

```
Euro.py, line  __str__
    return f'{self} €'

 [Previous line repeated 329 more times]

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use inheritance; a `Euro` is not a kind of `float`, and money should never be represented using `float`s due to the imprecision of the floating-point approximations of real numbers.

Instead, use *composition* to store an attribute representing the number of Euros, using something like `decimal.Decimal` to represent the euros-and-cents *exactly*.

```
from decimal import Decimal


class Euro:
    # In accordance with how to use super properly,
    # always accept and pass on unrecognized keyword arguments.
    def __init__(self, value, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.value = Decimal(value.strip('€'))

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.value} €'
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `super()` to call the parent's method and avoid the recursion error.

```
def __str__(self):
    return super().__str__() + ' €'


>>> g = Euro('123.23 €')
>>> print(g)
123.23 €
```

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up with the following code :

```
from decimal import Decimal

class Euro:
    def __init__(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, str):
            value = value.strip(' €')
        self.value = Decimal(value)

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Euro(self.value + other.value)

    def __sub__(self,other):
        return Euro(self.value - other.value)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.value} €'
```

I do not see the need to sub-class.
I've added support for +/- operators that return a Euro-object.

The result is :

```
g = Euro(1.00)
h = Euro('10.00 €')

print (h+g) # --> 11.00 €
print (h-g) # -->  9.00 €
```